# How to develop for .NET Micro Framework on Linux?

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, .net-micro-framework

Is there an IDE which will allow me to develop for the .net Micro Framework on Linux?

Maybe [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Netduino forums](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/21-preview-of-mono-support/):

> Soon, we'll be launching an open source project to port the .NET Micro Framework SDK to Mono for use on Mac and Linux.

They have released the [first alpha release](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/285-mfdeploy-v41-for-mac-os-x-and-linux-alpha-1/) of MFDeploy for Mono (Mac and Linux).

Comment: Deleted my answer as this is a yes! + upvote for the great find!

Answer (score 1):

Also, Netduino community member Brian Jepson has posted instructions on how to set up the Mono toolchain on Mac/Linux to compile .NET Micro Framework code.

Community members, with generous help from the Mono team, and also working on .NET MF support for the MonoDevelop IDE.  Temporarily, you'll want to use a different C# editor.

All the Mono-related news is at the following link:
http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/forum/12-mono/

Chris