# Deploy a .NET Micro framework application on USB device from GNU/Linux with Mono

Tags: linux, deployment, mono, .net-micro-framework

I started developing an application for a FEZ Panda device, using the .NET Micro Framework several weeks ago, on Windows.

As I really love GNU/Linux, I would like to use MonoDevelop to develop for this device.
Fortunately, there is an add-in for Mono, that allows deploying .NET Micro Framework applications. Unfortunately, it does not support USB deploy, and my computer has no serial port (it is a laptop).

Do you have any solution about my problem?

Thank you in advance,

ProgVal

EDIT: If there is another way that is not using MonoDevelop, I would like to test it too.

Comment: Try to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234329/how-to-develop-for-net-micro-framework-on-linux) question.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have neither a serial port on my computer (HP Pavilion dv7 1040ef) or a serial link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a USB to Serial adapter. Keep in mind that on most of these boards it is TTL not RS232 so you'll have to get a USB to TTL adapter.

They are usually very cheap. [This one should work.](http://www.robotshop.com/dfrobot-usb-to-ttl-convertor.html)